# Eagle - outlines/placeholder for smd (0603)

Tags: eaglecad, surface-mount

I'm a bit new in this area, trying to make a PCB for my little project and cannot find how to make placeholders for smd components in Eagle 9.2.2. Is it possible to have/create outlines for smd (resistors, capacitors etc) in the cam processor/silkscreen? Cannot find how. Would be great if there's an option to have different outlines types. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw anything (eg. lines) for example on the tNames layer of element footprint (in the library editor), so you could draw a rectangle around a resistor.

You can also use any other layer you want, but then you will have to make sure that that layer gets exported to the silkscreen gerber file before PCB fabrication.

Comment: Sure, but is it the only way - to modify standard library? It looks strange for noob like me - such a simple thing and such a “hackish” solution. I tried to include “keepout” layer to the silkscreen, but some components, like tantalum capacitors, have it filled including soldering places...

Comment: Well, could you please tell me how to modify this library? Or maybe there's a guide about that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You wish to make a placeholder, ie. a graphic that is visible on the so called PCB silkscreen?

All the data which goes into the silkscreen is collected from various layers in Eagle during the CAM process. There you can tell the CAM processor to include not only the standard tPlace and tName layers, but also such layers that you have created yourself. And they don't have to be in the component library, if you don't wish to modify those. (eventually you will, trust me :) )

Just create a new layer called MySilk (or something) and draw whatever pleases you using the ordinary line, arc, rectangle and whatever other tools are in Eagle nowadays (I'm still on v7). Then, when you are in the CAM Processor, make sure you add your layer in the "Silk" section.
There are many good tutorials online showing you the CAM process and how it's handled in Eagle.

Comment: Exactly, I'd like to add "rectangles" on the places where components shall be placed. CAM processor expects it to be placed on the "place" and "name" layers (of course I could add any other layer there). The problem is, that it's a bit hard to draw box "by hand" for every smd component, even if there are 10-20 of them. I found the "keepout" layer that was looking like a good choice, but for some components it is filled, not jus outline, so it will cover soldering pads.

Comment: You know, as a former programmer, it's a bit strange for me to modify a standard library, but it looks like it's really the simplest method